# invalid object type while creating the function

Tags: plsql

I'm pretty new to PL/SQL and can't understand what's wrong.

I create new type

`create or replace TYPE  "hmdtype" is object(entity_id number, tipe varchar2(200), oper_id number, message varchar2(200))`

Compile it, it's OK.

Then I'm trying to create function which returns this type:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION HDM RETURN HMDTYPE AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END HDM;
```

Try to compile. The error is Error(1,21): PLS-00905: object U216_DM2_6350.HMDTYPE is invalid

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you define an object name surrounded by "" it is case sensitive.
by default (without "") the name will be converted to uppercase.

try  `create or replace FUNCTION HDM RETURN "hmdtype" AS`

or redefine your type without ""

```
 create or replace TYPE hmdtype is object(entity_id number, tipe varchar2(200), oper_id number, message varchar2(200))
```

and your code should work

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can use the exact name as you have compiled as "" means exact name whatever you have given during compilation. Below code you can check it works

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "test_object" IS OBJECT
(
F_NM VARCHAR2(100),
L_NM VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function RETURN
"test_object"
AS
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
```